# Resource Governor on 2014 - CPU Not Being Throttled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, resource-governor

We have a specific query ran from our platform that consumes a lot of CPU on a box that already has Enterprise, so Resource Governor seemed like a good solution. I'm working on configuring it on our Dev server, but I'm not seeing the behavior I expected. The server has 4 cores and 16GB of memory with SQL Server 2014 on Server 2012 R2. I modified my resource pool and workload group like so:

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER RESOURCE POOL [CRTestRP] WITH(min_cpu_percent=5, max_cpu_percent=5,        cap_cpu_percent=5, 
min_memory_percent=0, max_memory_percent=100, AFFINITY SCHEDULER = AUTO, min_iops_per_volume=0, 
max_iops_per_volume=0)
GO
ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR RECONFIGURE 
GO
ALTER WORKLOAD GROUP [CRTestWG] WITH(group_max_requests=0, importance=Low,     request_max_cpu_time_sec=0, 
request_max_memory_grant_percent=25, request_memory_grant_timeout_sec=0, max_dop=1) USING [CRTestRP]
GO
ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR RECONFIGURE
```

I realize that Resource Governor won't kick in unless there's resource contention. To test the effects, I created a simulated workload on the server (it's a node that holds secondary replicas for Availability Groups, so mine are the only queries against) that raised CPU to an average of 88% using HammerDB. I've verified my test queries are getting correctly put under my workload group by the classifier function, and I have a few test queries ready to go.

After kicking off HammerDB and letting it run for a few minutes, I kicked off one of the CPU intensive queries. It does throttle that one effectively, holding it to ~5% CPU, however, when adding additional connections running the same query, CPU Usage for that workload group shoot up and negatively affect the default pool:

[image: Imgur]

In the graph above, CPU is at 100% for the entire time frame. The query in question doesn't seem to be relevent, other than the fact that it would go parallel if not for the MAXDOP 1 on the workload group.

Has anyone else seen this behavior? Has anyone had success with Resource Governor at all? What I really wanted out of it was that these queries wouldn't EVER be able to use above a certain amount of CPU for all of them combined at any one time, but it doesn't look like that's the case. It seems like there should be a configurable value for what CPU % constitutes "contention".

In any case, thank you all for your help!

Comment: Yes, of course, Resource Governor works. How *exactly* have you validated that the user you're connecting as is being properly identified by your classifier function?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look Aaron. I created a new SQL user and my classifier function keyed off SUSER_NAME() to put that user's sessions in the CRTestWG workload group. I then queried dm_resource_governor_workload_groups to find the group_ID for my workload group, then queried dm_exec_sessions for that group_ID. The only sessions in that group_ID were the two sessions I was running with the new sql user.

Comment: My problem is similar to yours. I explained at that link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674302/resource-governor-is-not-running-correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually ended up engaging Microsoft on this. The explanation that the engineer gave is that RG doesn't do a good job at throttling an OLTP vs. OLAP type workloads on the same instance. Our use case was a server with 1000's of tiny queries taking 1-2 ms, with occasional queries taking 6-7 seconds, with the longer queries being the ones we wanted to throttle. He acknowledged this was a bug and they would fix in a future release. Apparently, RG is getting rewritten from scratch in SQL 2016 to resolve these particular issues.